# How to start spring RESTful web service during tomcat startup

Tags: java, spring, rest, tomcat

I have followed spring's tutorial (link below) exactly to build a RESTful web service.  **My end goal is to have this service startup automatically as I startup the tomcat server via a WAR file**.  The web service starts and runs fine when executing the jar file, but when I attempted to generate a WAR file and place it in that directory I receive a 404 error when trying to hit the service, after starting the tomcat server.

Can anyone provide an example of how I should setup my web.xml file based on the objects in this tutorial so that I can startup this web service on a tomcat startup.  This information was not provided in the guide.  Your help would be greatly appreciated.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Comment: More info such as your project structure, stack trace is greatly appreciated. Sometimes following example does not work because of human mistake.

Comment: I already stated that everything is working fine with the project after following that example mentioned in the link.  I am just looking help on what to do next for starting the web service automatically using a WAR file, which is not documented in that guide to building the RESTful service.

Comment: Are you getting 404 when you put this URL http://localhost:8080/greeting on your browser ?

Comment: I am only getting a 404 when I attempt to generate a WAR file and then put that in my tomcat webapps directory and startup tomcat.  When I follow the guide, the service runs as expected after generating an executable jar and then execute java file from the command line.